# ng-repeat for tr to add rows dynamically.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<tr class="workTime" ng-repeat="worktime in doctor.shift" >                                 
    <td><select name="multipleSelect" class="form-control selectpicker"          
     id="multipleSelect" ng-model="doctor.shift.workDays" multiple>
          <option ng-repeat="days in weekdays">{{days}}</option>                                      
       </select>
   </td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model =                      
    "doctor.shift.workFrom"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model =     
     "doctor.shift.workTo">   
    </td>
    <td><span class="glyphicon **glyphicon-plus** glyph_size "  ng-
     click="addWorkTime()" aria-hidden="true "></span></td>
</tr>
```

I am new to Angular. I would like to repeat the tr on click of the glyphicon-plus. I am not sure how to do this. I am not fetching any data. I just want to add a row with the respective fields on click of the glyphicon-plus. Can some please help me to resolve this. And if I have to write any script. What script do I have to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's the sort answer:

```
var app = angular.module('main', []); 
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    // create an object to hold the collection
    $scope.doctor = {
        shift : {
        worktimes: []
      }
    };

    $scope.addWorkTime = function() {
        // add an element to the end of the array
      $scope.doctor.shift.worktimes.push( {
                workDay: 1,
            workFrom: '9:00',
            workTo: '22:00'
      });
    };
    // add an initial row - if there are no rows, there's no add button!
    $scope.addWorkTime();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cglist/t661eh5y/5/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=t661eh5y

The long answer is that there's some funny stuff in your html that makes it clear you're just getting started with Angular. 
For starters, when you say this:
ng-repeat="worktime in doctor.shift"
..."worktime" is a temporary variable created solely for iterating over the object or (more likely) collection. Therefore, in the repeated template, you'd want to bind to things like: "worktime.workFrom"
You'll see that I tweaked your html and your data model to make it all work, while trying to guess at what you were trying to accomplish.

Next, for the options on your select box, the current way of doing it is with "ngOptions", and not "ngRepeat" : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: May I know the reason for adding worktimes, Can't it be like doctor.shift by changing the ng-repeat for tr and for each ng-model I want doctor.shift because doctor would create a JSON object on post. Could I do something like that

Comment: Yes, you could, but I couldn't tell just from your html how you wanted the model to work. The repeated item in the loop is named "worktime". whether that's coming from doctor.shifts[] or doctor.shift.worktimes[] I don't know  because it wasn't obvious to me where the collection was from your html. The html for the "td" definitions would be the same either way, only the part of the ng-repeat after the "in" would change...